Getting an ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError...) exception on airflow
I am working on an airflow version 1.9.0 (Python 2.7) while starting the airflow I am getting the below exception, everything in the SQL/SQLite db looks good, can someone help me debug this
below is an exception I get on dag view, i am getting a similar error on dag runs (backfill, runs)
                          ____/ (  (    )   )  \___
                         /( (  (  )   _    ))  )   )\
                       ((     (   )(    )  )   (   )  )
                     ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                    ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
                   ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
                  (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
                  ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
                 ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
                  (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
                 ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
                  ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
                   (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
                   ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                            (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                          (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                           (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                         (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                          (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                        (        |(||(||)||||        )
                          (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                        (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: <>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/airflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/mnt/airflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[...rest of traceback see edit history...]
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/mnt/airflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/mnt/airflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/mnt/airflow/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[(\\'dag_id\\', u\\'test-dag\\')]'')' at line 1") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (%(dttm)s, %(dag_id)s, %(task_id)s, %(event)s, %(execution_date)s, %(owner)s, %(extra)s)'] [parameters: {'task_id': None, 'extra': "[('dag_id', u'test-dag')]", 'execution_date': None, 'event': 'graph', 'owner': None, 'dttm': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 23, 2, 15, 13, 141266), 'dag_id': u'test-dag'}]

sql table ddl (it is created by airflow itself using airflow.cfg path, if i am not wrong).
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dttm` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dag_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `execution_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32179 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

I am new to this older version, I gave it a try to check all possibilities, i have restarted airflow as well, but no help
